# About the evaluation of covariance of linear Gaussian model in PRML

Tags: machine-learning, probability, normal-distribution, graphical-model, bayesian-network

Section 8.1.4 of *Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning* introduces the linear Gaussian model where each node has distribution

$$
p(x_i \big|pa_i) = \mathcal{N}\left ( x_i \Bigg| \sum_{j\in pa_i}w_{ij}x_j + b_i, v_i \right )
$$

and let

$$
x_i = \sum_{j\in pa_i}w_{ij}x_j + b_i + \sqrt{v_i}\epsilon_i
$$

where

$$
\epsilon_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)
$$

Then it shows the process of deriving the covariance:

$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{cov}[x_i, x_j] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\left(x_i - \mathbb{E}[x_i]\right)\left(x_j - \mathbb{E}[x_j]\right)\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left [ (x_i - \mathbb{E}[x_i])\left \{ \sum_{k\in pa_j}w_{jk}(x_k - \mathbb{E}[x_k]) + \sqrt{v_j}\epsilon_j \right \} \right ]\\
&=\sum_{k\in pa_j}w_{jk}\operatorname{cov}[x_i, x_k] + I_{ij}v_j
\end{align}
$$

How to obtain the second term $I_{ij}v_j$?